# The More link for fetching other results in PHP?

Tags: php, html

Please Do see the code below .  . I have restricted the results to 3 and i have added a more link at the end but it isnt working ! Can you please check this out . . . I have tried multiple ways

```
<?php 
  if(count($this->store_list)>0){
            $number_output = 0;
foreach($this->store_list as $store){
$number_output++;
if($number_output > 3) break;
        ?>
   <div id="menu">         
  <span class="cons_title fl"><a href="<?php echo PATH.'store/'.$store->title_url.'.html'; ?>"><h2><?php echo ucfirst($store->name); ?></h2></a></span>

             <div class="cons_bot fl clr">

                  <ul>
                    <li><h4><?php echo $store->address1; ?>,</h4></li>
                    <li><h4><?php echo $store->address2; ?>,</h4></li>
                    <li><h4><?php echo $store->area_name; ?>,</h4></li>
                    <li><h4><?php echo ucfirst($store->city_name); ?>,</h4></li>
                    <li><h4><?php echo $store->pin; ?></h4></li>
                    <li><h4>PH:</h4><h4><?php echo $store->phone; ?></h4></li>
                  </ul>
                  </div>

</div>  
 echo "$newtext <a href=more_details.php> more...</a>
```

Comment: Had we had this information before, we could have addressed this all in one question. The counter is not actually what you want in this case, as you now want to utilize the LIMIT and OFFSET properties of SQL queries. You want to LIMIT to 3 and OFFSET by some number X, passing that X on to the next page in a $_GET variable.

Answer (score 0):

you need to indicate to your code where to start from on the next page for example, you could use the following link: `href="more_details.php?position=3"` and that page will have the link: `href="more_details.php?position=6"` and so on.
In your code you would use the value of `position` to figure our from what offset to display the next set of results.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us details on what isn't working? If you are talking about having the more details page not working, then you need to post that.

Right away though I see that you forgot to finish your last link and finish your if/foreach statement, unless you arent showing us all the code.

Its also confusing why you have a a header tag in your list tags.

Answer (score 0):

on the first load of the page, you set a session variable on which you place the last row you loaded (let's say 30) and the rows you are about to display (rows 1-30).

when you click "more...", you need to know in the PHP side that it was the "more..." button. if it's "more..", grab the last row number stored in the session and add 1. that will be your starting point for another 30 items. get the items 31-60, **append** it to the previously stored rows (the ones in the session). then render them. now you have 60 items displayed, 60 as your last item count and 60 in store. repeat the procedure for more.

so you ask why you need to determine if it was the "more..." button. if you didn't, every load to the page would load the previously stored items plus the next 30. so if it isn't the "more..." button, clear the session and start a new 30 items.